Is there an established notion of natural transformation for cofunctors?
A natural transformation $\eta:F\to G$ assumes that we have functors $F,G:C \to D$. But what if we have $F,G$ where either of $F,G$ is a cofunctor (i.e. contra-variant functor)? There are four possibilities. $F$ could be a cofunctor and $G$ not, or $G$ could be a cofunctor but $F$ not, etc.
Is there a generalized definition of natural transformation in this context?
I would guess that if $F$ is contravariant but $G$ is not, the commutativity condition of $\eta$ would have to change, and be something like: for all $f:X\to Y$, we have the commutative diagram condition $\eta_Y = G(f) \circ \eta_X \circ F(f)$, where $F(f): F(Y) \to F(X)$ and $G(f) : G(X) \to G(Y)$.
EDIT: Apparently this is a special case of a "dinatural" transformation as explained in this answer, which is quite a bit more general. My question now becomes, does this special case of dinatural transformation have an established name and definition?

To be clear, you're talking about what the nLab calls a retrofunctor?

@S.C., no I did not know about that notion. I meant contravariant functors.

This is similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120342/natural-transformation-between-covariant-and-contravariant-functor

@NaïmFavier, you are right, I've edited my question.

Now the answer is no; I think most people would understand if you just talked about a dinatural transformation from $F : C \to D$ to $G : C^\mathrm{op} \to D$.

@NaïmFavier, actually it seems like in this context it does matter whether we define a contravariant functor as a functor $C^{op} \to D$ or as $C \to D^{op}$? Because the commutativity condition is different?

The latter definition makes it unclear what the direction of the components of the transformation should be. Just stick to the first one.
